# Unable to present Apple Pay Authorization Controller

Tags: swift, swift3, ios10, applepay, ios10.2

When I attempt to present a PKPaymentAuthorizationController with `present(completion: _)` it fails without any further information.

Here's how I'm presenting it:

```
let paymentSummaryItems: [PKPaymentSummaryItem] = <HIDDEN>

let paymentRequest = PKPaymentRequest()
paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = paymentSummaryItems
paymentRequest.merchantIdentifier = <HIDDEN>
paymentRequest.merchantCapabilities = .capability3DS
paymentRequest.countryCode = "US"
paymentRequest.currencyCode = "USD"
paymentRequest.supportedNetworks = [.visa, .amex, .masterCard, .discover]
paymentRequest.requiredShippingAddressFields = [.email]

let paymentController = PKPaymentAuthorizationController(paymentRequest: paymentRequest)
paymentController.delegate = self

paymentController.present { success in
    if success {
      print("Presented payment controller")
    } else {
      print("Failed to present payment controller")
    }
}
```

Every time I try, I get the message "Failed to present payment controller", and no Apple Pay Authorization modal appears.

I added a `PKPaymentAuthorizationController.canMakePayments()` check, and that returns true. I'm not sure what could be going wrong. The same code (with a different `merchantIdentifier`) works in my other Apple Pay projects with no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, for anybody who encounters this issue in the future.

It turns out there was a problem with one of the NSDecimalNumbers in my array of PKPaymentSummaryItems, it didn't properly convert to a decimal and resulted in `amount` being set to `NaN`. Once I fixed it, the controller appeared properly.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a typo at any of the properties of `PKPaymentRequest` object, that will cause this behaviour. Please double check that following properties are correct:

- `merchantID` should match your merchantID in Capabilities.
- `currencyCode` should be three-letter ISO 4217 currency code.
- `countryCode` should be two-letter ISO 3166 country code.
- `decimalNumbers` in paymentSummaryItems

In my case, I was trying to just test the feature with hardcoded merchantID and it turned out it was misspelled. In that case `PKPaymentRequest` and `PKPaymentAuthorizationController` (or `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController`) will be initialised successfully but when you present controller, it simply wouldn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it using following steps: 1 of which could be correct answer.

- In App target capabilities, enable Apple wallet and Apple pay
- Include correct merchant id, in the Apple pay list
- Change the merchant id in entitlements
- If any errors in provisining, enable "Automatically manage signing" provisioning profile (uncheck/check if reqd.)

[image: App target capabilities screenshot]